# Pass variable into boto3 client command

Tags: python, boto3

How I can pass a variable value into boto3 client because it returns `None`

I have 1.csv file

```
account-id action az-id bytes dstaddr dstport end instance-id interface-id log-status packets pkt-dstaddr pkt-srcaddr protocol region srcaddr srcport start sublocation-id sublocation-type subnet-id tcp-flags type version vpc-id
986667839874 ACCEPT use1-az2 4243299 10.0.203.110 7000 1613466970 i-07579d3b27895f4 eni-09a50609b401b62 OK 11315 10.0.203.110 10.0.204.253 6 us-east-1 10.0.204.253 49629 1613466953 - - subnet-dfa26cf1 0 IPv4 4 vpc-82b26efb
```

which I convert to dict

```py
with open("1.csv", 'r') as file:
    csv_file = csv.DictReader(file, delimiter=" ")
    for row in csv_file:
```

then I can get instance ID

```py
idd = [value for value in rowsdic.values()][7]
```

`print(idd)` - returns list of correct values

then I convert to string to pass the value of `idd` and convert back to `dict`

```py
desr_filter_strn = str(dict({'Name': 'resource-id', 'Values': [idd]}))
desr_filter_dict = ast.literal_eval(desr_filter_strn)
```

`print(instance_tag_name(desr_filter_dict))` - return correct strings

then I pass `desr_filter_dict` to get a list of Tag Name value but have got return `None`

```py
for tag in ec2.describe_tags(Filters=[desr_filter_dict])['Tags']:
    if tag['Key'] == 'Name':
    print(tag['Value'])
```

However if I set variable `idd = 'i-0b0dd4328eb0f'` I have got tag Name value.

Thanks in advance
Rostyslav

p.s.
I use `import csv` to convert this

```
account-id action az-id bytes dstaddr dstport end instance-id interface-id log-status packets pkt-dstaddr pkt-srcaddr protocol region srcaddr srcport start sublocation-id sublocation-type subnet-id tcp-flags type version vpc-id

986667839874 ACCEPT use1-az2 226 10.0.203.141 9042 1613466923 i-4328eb0f9a1 eni-ae5695c607 OK 4 10.0.203.141 10.0.248.232 6 us-east-1 10.0.248.232 54776 1613466907 - - subnet-a26cf1 0 IPv4 4 vpc-82b6efb
```

into dict

```
{'account-id': '986667839874', 'action': 'ACCEPT', 'az-id': 'use1-az2', 'bytes': '226', 'dstaddr': '10.0.203.141', 'dstport': '9042', 'end': '1613466923', 'instance-id': 'i-4328eb0f9a1', 'interface-id': 'eni-ae5695c607', 'log-status': 'OK', 'packets': '4', 'pkt-dstaddr': '10.0.203.141', 'pkt-srcaddr': '10.0.248.232', 'protocol': '6', 'region': 'us-east-1', 'srcaddr': '10.0.248.232', 'srcport': '54776', 'start': '1613466907', 'sublocation-id': '-', 'sublocation-type': '-', 'subnet-id': 'subnet-a26cf1', 'tcp-flags': '0', 'type': 'IPv4', 'version': '4', 'vpc-id': 'vpc-82b6efb'}
```

Comment: Your code is incomplete. What happens after `for row in csv_file:`? What is `rowsdic`?

Comment: @Marcin I have edited my question and add text after p.s.
I use `import csv` to convert space-delimited log into dict.

Comment: ಠ_ಠ What in the world are you doing with `str(dict(...))` and `ast.literal_eval` there?! Why not `desr_filter_dict = dict(...)` directly?

Comment: To boil the issue down to its core: `print(desr_filter_dict)` right before your `ec2.describe_tags` call and see the difference between the working and the not-working version…

Comment: Also, in the file you have `i-07579d3b27895f4` but you are using `i-0b0dd4328eb0f` for manual test. Shouldn't they be same?

Comment: ```desr_filter_strn = str(dict({'Name': 'resource-id', 'Values': [idd]}))
desr_filter_dict = ast.literal_eval(desr_filter_strn)```
I use this to insert into `'Values': [idd]` value and convert this string back to `dict` to pass into boto3 code. 

in this example, instance ID doesn't matter I had changed it to avoid publicity real IDs

Comment: You're turning a dict into a string and then parse it back to a dict. That's superfluous madness.

Comment: @deceze yes, of course. I will improve later when I will have resolved this issue.